# Mongodb:Right way to collect data from two collections?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I have two collections: one is `items` and the second one is `user_item_history`. I want to fetch items with their status. Status of each item is stored in `user_item_history`, and other details of the item are in the `items` collection. we have to filter data for particular user and category of item. so user_id and category is in user_item_history collection.

`user_item_history`:

```
{
    "_id" : NumberLong(25424),
    "_class" : "com.samepinch.domain.registration.UserItemHistory",
    "user_id" : NumberLong(25416),
    "item_id" : NumberLong(26220),
    "catagoryPreference" : "BOTH",
    "preference" : 0.6546536707079772,
    "catagory" : "FOOD",
    "status" : 1,
    "createdDate" : ISODate("2015-09-02T07:50:36.760Z"),
    "updatedDate" : ISODate("2015-09-02T07:55:24.105Z")
}
```

`items`:

```
{
    "_id" : NumberLong(26220),
    "_class" : "com.samepinch.domain.item.Item",
    "itemName" : "Shoes",
    "categoryName" : "SHOPPING",
    "attributes" : [
        "WESTERN",
        "CASUAL",
        "ELEGANT",
        "LATEST"
    ],
    "isAccessed" : false,
    "imageUrl" : "0bd2838e-9349-432a-a200-6e6b659e853eitemcompressed.jpg",
    "catagoryPreference" : "FEMALE",
    "startDate" : ISODate("2015-11-26T18:30:00Z"),
    "endDate" : ISODate("2015-11-27T18:30:00Z"),
    "location" : {
        "coordinates" : [
            77.24149558372778,
            28.56973445677584
        ],
        "type" : "Point",
        "radius" : 2000
    },
    "createdDate" : ISODate("2015-11-16T10:49:11.858Z"),
    "updatedDate" : ISODate("2015-11-16T10:49:11.858Z")
}
```

As the final result, I would like to have documents of this format:

```
{
    item_id:26220,
    status:1,
    imageUrl: "0bd2838e-9349-432a-a200-6e6b659e853eitemcompressed.jpg"
}
```

Comment: Which version of MongoDB are you on? Are you able to use MongoDB 3.2?

Comment: i am using  3.0.6 version of MongoDB. I can switch to MongoDB 3.2,there is no issue with it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update to MongoDB 3.2 and you'll be able to use the [**`$lookup`**](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#) aggregation stage, which works similarly to SQL joins.

## One-to-many relationship

If there are many corresponding `user_item_history` documents for each `items` document, you can get a list of item statuses as an array.

#### Query

```js
db.items.aggregate([
{
    $lookup:
    {
        from: "user_item_history",
        localField: "_id",
        foreignField: "item_id",
        as: "item_history"
    }
},
{
    $project:
    {
        item_id: 1,
        status: "$item_history.status",
        imageUrl: 1
    }
}])
```

#### Example Output

```json
{
    "_id" : NumberLong(26220),
    "imageUrl" : "0bd2838e-9349-432a-a200-6e6b659e853eitemcompressed.jpg",
    "status" : [ 1 ]
},
{
    "_id" : NumberLong(26233),
    "imageUrl" : "0bd2838e-9349-432a-a200-6e6b659e853eitemcompressed.jpg",
    "status" : [ 1, 2 ]
}
```

## One-to-one relationship

If there's only one corresponding history document for every item, you can use the following approach to get the exact format you requested:

#### Query

```js
db.items.aggregate([
{
    $lookup:
    {
        from: "user_item_history",
        localField: "_id",
        foreignField: "item_id",
        as: "item_history"
    }
},
{
    $unwind: "$item_history"
},
{
    $project:
    {
        item_id: 1,
        status: "$item_history.status",
        imageUrl: 1
    }
}])
```

#### Example Output

```json
{
    "_id" : NumberLong(26220),
    "imageUrl" : "0bd2838e-9349-432a-a200-6e6b659e853eitemcompressed.jpg",
    "status" : 1
}
```

Please bear in mind that with every additional aggregation pipeline stage you add, the performance deteriorates. So you may prefer the one-to-many query even if you have a one-to-one relationship.

## Applying filtering

In your edit, you added this:

> we have to filter data for particular user and category of item. so user_id and category is in user_item_history collection

To filter your results, you should add a [**`$match`**](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) step to your query:

```js
db.items.aggregate([
{
    $lookup:
    {
        from: "user_item_history",
        localField: "_id",
        foreignField: "item_id",
        as: "item_history"
    }
},
{
    $unwind: "$item_history"
},
{
    $match:
    {
        "item_history.user_id": NumberLong(25416),
        "item_history.catagory": "FOOD"
    }
},
{
    $project:
    {
        item_id: 1,
        status: "$item_history.status",
        imageUrl: 1
    }
}])
```

Please note that "category" is misspelled as "catagory" in your example data, so I also had to misspell it in the query above.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ,its work for me. but how do I add criteria in it. I also want to know item status  for a particular user ?

Comment: @Abhisheksaini use [**`$match`**](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) to specify criteria.

Comment: Sir please i need  help,i have updated question,so please update your answer with match criteria.

Comment: @Abhisheksaini I have updated my answer. Hopefully this should work for you. If you have any further questions, please post them as separate questions and don't modify this one anymore.

Comment: Sir its not working. Now  I am not getting any result, even I have a user for that id also.

Comment: @Abhisheksaini in your data in the `user_item_history` collection, is the field called `catagory`? Or is it `category`?

Comment: its a catagory in my documents. but even i searched only with  the user_id its also not giving anything.

Comment: @Abhisheksaini I have tested the query and it works for me. If you give me a dump of your database (e.g. generated with [**`mongodump`**](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongodump/)), I can look into your problem.

Comment: how can i send you a dump? any email id or any other source?

Comment: Thanks . I have mailed you. :)

Comment: @Abhisheksaini in your database, `items` has IDs from 26145 to 26291. `userItemHistory` (which is **not** the same as `user_item_history` in your example) has `item_id` values from 25199 to 25208. There are no matching records between these two tables! The problem is not with the query, the problem is with your data.

Comment: Thank you sir. Above query is working fine for me. I was doing something wrong.Now its working. Thank you so much.